# pyqt LCD to monitor a running function duration

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a long running function that takes minutes and hours. I need to monitor how long it takes for the function to finish (minute by minute). I tried to use time.time, but can't display the increasing minutes and hours. Can you help me, to display the update of the running function

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.lcdnumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lcdnumber)

    def somefunction(self):
        # long run function that takes minutes and hours
        #
        self.lcdnumber.display() # How can I display every minute and display
        #




if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable answer by using QTime.currentTime(). It works exactly like what I want